# 'getView' overrides nothing

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, overriding, getview

I am new about android studio. I tried to use ArrayAdapter. But when i complete my codes, it says "'getView' overrides nothing".I getting this error in "return teksatirview code.
this is my arrayadapter class:

```
package com.example.burcrehberi
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.teksatir.view.*


class BurcArrayAdapter(
var gelencontext: Context,
resource: Int,
textViewResourceId: Int,
var burcAdlari: Array<String>,
var burcTarih: Array<String>,
var burcResimleri: Array<Int>
) : ArrayAdapter<String>(gelencontext, resource, textViewResourceId, burcAdlari) {

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {

    var teksatirview = convertView

    if (teksatirview == null) {

        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(gelencontext)
        teksatirview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teksatir, parent, false)


    }

    var burcImageView = teksatirview?.imgburcsembol
    var burcisim = teksatirview?.tvburcadi
    var burctarih = teksatirview?.tvburctarih

    burcImageView?.setImageResource(burcResimleri[position])
    burcisim?.setText(burcAdlari[position])
    burctarih?.setText(burcTarih[position])

    return teksatirview
}

}
```

Comment: could you attach all code of your adapter?

Comment: I editted my code now. You can see all codes of adapter class.

Comment: try using viewHolder or just inflate the view and its child by using the findViewById() method instead of taking form the convertView.

Comment: I was adding viewHolder, but nothing change.

Comment: while adding viewHolder you would have to use a getTag() method

Comment: I have explained the usage of viewHolder in the answer. Its in Java as a good at it I guess. if you need any help in converting to kotlin just mention it. May be I can help you out. Hope that solves your issue.

Comment: Simply check whether all the parameters and return values have proper nullability (as in method you're trying to override). I bet `parent` and return type are wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem in `parent: ViewGroup?`. According to signature it must be non-null type. But it's nullable in your signature, so it's completely different function in kotlin. Just change to:

```
 override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
```

And return type `View?` to `View` too.

Comment: Yep this is correct according to the kotlin getView() signature is as you mentioned and its given in the android documentations.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/ArrayAdapter

Comment: I remove "?" from ViewGroup.  This time i get this error:Type mismatch: inferred type is View? but View was expected

Comment: @akiilhan Change function return type View? to View too.

Comment: this is my getview code now:  override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View, parent: ViewGroup): View {   But i get same error.

Comment: @akiilhan But convertView: View must be convertView: View?

Comment: @akiilhan just copypaste and replace line from my answer

Comment: @DmitriiNechepurenko I copypaste your answer. Now i am getting this error:type mismatch: inferred type is View? but View was expected -> it says for " return teksatirview"

Comment: @akiilhan Yes, because return type must be non-null view, but teksatirview is nullable `View?`. Change `return teksatirview` to `return teksatirview!!`

Comment: @DmitriiNechepurenko Thank you so much. It Works.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you code should be like this:

```
// first check your types for function you're overriding
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    // then rewrite internal code to prevent unnecessary optionality
    val teksatirview = convertView ?: {
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(gelencontext)
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.teksatir, parent, false)!!
    }()

    val burcImageView = teksatirview.imgburcsembol
    val burcisim = teksatirview.tvburcadi
    val burctarih = teksatirview.tvburctarih

    burcImageView.setImageResource(burcResimleri[position])
    burcisim.setText(burcAdlari[position])
    burctarih.setText(burcTarih[position])

    return teksatirview
}
```

Comment: replace View to View? solve isssue in new lib versions.

Answer (score 1):

The posts may be correct, but in this case the code will not work in an optimized way. It is regenerated for each view object rotated in the inflater page. This will result in an inefficient output if the data source is large. If the signNames [positions] are added and tested in the log records, what I am trying to say will be clearer. As a more optimized solution, I can recommend:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    var teksatirview = convertView

    if (teksatirview == null) {

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(gelencontext)
        teksatirview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teksatir, parent, false)
        Log.e("TEST","inflation applied ${burcAdlari[position]}")

    }

    var burcImageView = teksatirview?.imgburcsembol
    var burcisim = teksatirview?.tvburcadi
    var burctarih = teksatirview?.tvburctarih

    burcImageView?.setImageResource(burcResimleri[position])
    burcisim?.setText(burcAdlari[position])
    burctarih?.setText(burcTarih[position])

    return teksatirview!!
}
```